# Creating a volume slider in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, slider, tkinter-scale

I'm trying to use `.get()` to access entry from my `Scale` but the volume doesn't change when I move slider. I'm using `pygame` mixer too btw.

Relevant code;

```
def change_vol():
    sounds.music.set_volume(vol.get())
#########################################
def play_music():
    load_music()
    sounds.music.play()
    pass
##########################
def load_music():
    sounds.music.load("fakeplastic.wav")


vol = Scale(
    sound_box,
    from_ = 0,
    to = 1,
    orient = HORIZONTAL ,
    resolution = .1,
)
vol.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
```

If you'd like me to post any other snippets please ask, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to assign the `Scale`'s `command` option to `change_vol` so that the function is called each time you adjust the scale:

```
vol = Scale(
    sound_box,
    from_ = 0,
    to = 1,
    orient = HORIZONTAL ,
    resolution = .1,
    ####################
    command=change_vol
    ####################
)
```

You will also need to redefine `change_vol` to accept the event object that will be sent to it every time you move the scale:

```
def change_vol(_=None):
    sounds.music.set_volume(vol.get())
```

I did `_=None` to make it clear that you are not using the argument inside the function.

Comment: Adding that gives the error; Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1490, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: change_vol() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @DamhanRichardson - Ah, an event object is being sent to `change_vol`.  See my edit.

Comment: You're the best! couldnt find this anywhere online.